# how I could split a hash in ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash, split

Im trying to split I hash but not get nothing

this is my code

```
   start="1,4,1,0,1,1,1,30,12,;1,4,1,2,1,1,1,30,29,;1,5,1,2,0,1,1,30,29,;1,4,1,2,0,1,1,30,29,;1,4,1,0,1,1,1,30,29,;"
  options = {"start" => "1,4,1,0,1,1,1,30,12,;1,4,1,2,1,1,1,30,29,;1,5,1,2,0,1,1,30,29,;1,4,1,2,0,1,1,30,29,;1,4,1,0,1,1,1,30,29,;"}

   File.open("mmmm3", "a" )do |f|
      f.puts #{options[start]}.split(";")[1]
 end
```

please help me with this

Comment: As you can see from the StackOverflow syntax highlighting, you have commented out your code. Remove `#{` and `}`. What you want to print is `options[start].split(";")`

Comment: Why the repetition here? Why not `options = { "start" => start }`?

Comment: Where do the values for `start` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`options[start]` returns a string. But the problem is you have mistakenly commented out your code. Remove `#{` and `}`. What you want to print is

```
options[start].split(";")[1]
```

which will contain the second group (since `[0]` would return the first)

Comment: With the OP's code, `options[start]` would return `nil`.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't even notice that. I was still thinking about the code he posted in a different question a few minutes prior.